# Why is HAProxy forwarding HTTP2 requests as HTTP 1.1?

Tags: http, https, wireshark, haproxy

I'm trying to configure a load balancer between 2 servers with HAPoxy, this is my configuration:

```
frontend haproxynode
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/isel.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    mode tcp
    default_backend backendnodes
    
 backend backendnodes
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server node1 192.168.1.5:80 check
    server node2 192.168.1.6:80 check
```

This is my network:

[image: network]

I'm running a word press server in both server VM's. And I'm using h2load to do the benchmarking.
When I use the command `h2load -n 30 -c 30 https://192.168.1.26/blog/` I get this:

[image]

As you can see the application protocol is h2, but in WireShark the requests appear as HTTP 1.1, why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your servers are supporting http/2 without encryption ?

Try this:

```
backend servers
   mode http
   server S1 XXX.XXX.XXX:80 proto h2
   server S2 XXX.XXX.XXX:80 proto h2
```

If you have encryption enabled try this:

```
backend servers
   mode http
   server S1 XXX.XXX.XXX:443 ssl alpn h2
   server S2 XXX.XXX.XXX:443 ssl alpn h2
```

Comment: The server software might support unencrypted http/2 but it's often not enabled by default. E.g. Apache needs `Protocols h2c http/1.1` and nginx needs `listen 80 http2;`